# why does smartphones start to lag after few years of their launch?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have seen that every smartphone that used to be flagship device start facing lag after a span of time. why does the same RAM, same CPU becomes slower over the years.
Taking example of Samsung device from S3 to S6.

> Samsung claimed S3 as most powerful device on May 2012

but now its not even having power why does it happen irrespective of the android updates.

> similarly Samsung galaxy S4 now lags and freezes.

Are the new software updates and apps this heavy that the older device cannot handle?

Comment: My S3 was running very slowly after several years, due to apps and other data that was stored on it.  I reset the phone, wiped all the data, set up Android again and it was working fast again, almost like new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the same reason computers do, which you alluded to:

New OS versions, and new software, all need more, with time. Every new main version of an OS or app is built with a more recent generation of devices in mind. They expect more RAM, and therefore use more, they expect faster processors, and therefore do more, etc. Over time, the demands of the same software, as it's updated, will overwhelm the older hardware.

There's also one other factor, which is that flash memory, over time, loses some speed as well. The more writes to it, the more "junk" (I'm not going to get too technical here) builds up, the more work that has to be done to get around that and clean it up, and the slower it gets. Happens with high-end SSDs (look at the problems the Samsung 840 EVO had), and happens with the lowest of flash memory.

All combined, you can't really expect your smartphone to be running like when it was new by the time your contract is up.